# split the words of a paragraph and put individual words inside seperate span element and animate them

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a paragraph element which has display property hidden.I split each of that paragraph words and put them inside individual span element.Then i want to give them some effects which involves each word will come from different locations and sit in correct order.But here each word is not showing such effect rather they arise from lower position to upper positions.how can i achieve the effect i am hoping for?please help me out!!!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/R92f9/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myp{
display:none;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>if you miss the action ,please reload the page</h3>
<p id='myp'>the earth moves round the sun</p>
<script>
var para;
var para_array=[];
var string;
var splits;
var ids=[];
var m;
var time=10;
k=50;

function init(){

  para=document.getElementById('myp');
  string=para.innerHTML.toString();
  splits=string.split(' ');

  for(i=0;i<splits.length;i++){
    para_array.push(splits[i]);

  }

  for(i=0;i<para_array.length;i++){
    m=document.createElement('span');
    var id='span'+i;
    m.setAttribute('id',id);
    var left=window.innerWidth-(Math.floor(Math.round()*900)+800);
    var top=window.innerHeight-(Math.floor(Math.round()*400)+50);

    ids.push(m.id);
    var style='position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top+';color:red;margin-right:30px;opacity:0;display:block;transition:all 1s ease-in-out;'
    m.setAttribute('style',style);
    m.innerHTML=para_array[i];
    document.body.appendChild(m);
    k+=70;
  }

  var t=setTimeout(function(){
    for(i=0;i<para_array.length;i++){

      var g=document.getElementById('span'+i);
      g.style.top="200px";
      g.style.left=150+time+"px";
      g.style.opacity=1;

      g.style.transform="rotate(360deg)";
      time+=50;
    }
  },100);
}

window.onload=init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to apply these effects? Or how to "split the words of a paragraph and put individual words inside seperate span element", as the title says? It seems you've already done that part.

Comment: actually i was able to split the words and put them inside individual span element..the problem was giving them the desired effects...

Comment: why giving downvote to the post.was the question not clear?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to append 'px' to your top and left values:

```
var style='position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top+';color:red;margin-right:30px;opacity:0;display:block;transition:all 1s ease-in-out;'
```

should be :

```
var style='position:absolute;left:'+left+'px;top:'+top+'px;color:red;margin-right:30px;opacity:0;display:block;transition:all 1s ease-in-out;'
```

also , i believe you wanted to have `Math.random` instead of `Math.round`

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav5430/R92f9/1/

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the mistakes :)) .those were terrible mistakes i suppose!! actually i didn't give any argument for Math.round().say Math.round(X)...shouldn't i get some error massage for that from the browser??but i didn't get any :(

Comment: no the browser wouldn't give an error, the function without any argument will just return NaN and so your left and top will be NaN

Answer (score 1):

gaurav5430 already answered your question. I just wanted to offer some cleaned up code for you. Also altered your jsfiddle to make the words evenly spaced.

http://jsfiddle.net/R92f9/2/

```
var para = document.getElementById('myp');

function init(target){
    var words = para.innerHTML.toString().split(' ');
    var spans = [];
    var left = window.innerWidth-(Math.floor(Math.random()*900)+800);
    var top = 1000-(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+50);
    var style='position:absolute; left:'+left+'px; top:'+top+'px; color:red; margin-right:30px; opacity:0; display:block; transition:all 1s ease-in-out;';
    var wordSpacing = 10;

    for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++){

        var span = document.createElement('span');

        span.setAttribute('style', style);
        span.innerHTML = words[i];
        document.body.appendChild(span);

        spans.push(span);

    }

    var t=setTimeout(function(){

        var currentLeft = 150;

        for(var i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
            var span = spans[i];

            span.style.top       = "200px";
            span.style.left      = currentLeft+"px";
            span.style.opacity   = 1;
            span.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";

            currentLeft += span.offsetWidth + wordSpacing;

        }

    },1000);
}

window.onload=function(){init(para, 10);};
```

Comment: No problem. Also, I didn't do it here, but it's best to leave you're styling in your stylesheet rather than adding inline styling via javascript. You could achieve this by moving all of your styling from this script, except `top` and `left`, to classes in your stylesheet then just add and remove the classes with your script. So basically the only css your script adds inline is that which needs to be calculated in your script.